# Add all search results to state React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do a little dictionary searcher in React and I have a problem with saving all data in searchResult state.
My code:

```
const Search = () => {
  const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState({});
  const handleSearch = e => {
    const finded = e.target.value;
    console.log(finded);
    if (finded === "") {
      setSearchResult({});
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
        if (
          datas[i].pol.includes(finded) ||
          datas[i].eng.includes(finded) ||
          datas[i].ger.includes(finded) ||
          datas[i].ned.includes(finded) ||
          datas[i].spa.includes(finded) ||
          datas[i].fra.includes(finded) ||
          datas[i].ita.includes(finded)
        ) {
          console.log(datas[i].pol, datas[i].eng, datas[i].ger);

          setSearchResult({
            ...searchResult,
            pol: datas[i].pol,
            eng: datas[i].eng,
            ger: datas[i].ger,
            ned: datas[i].ned,
            spa: datas[i].spa,
            fra: datas[i].fra,
            ita: datas[i].ita
          });

          console.log("searchResult", searchResult);
        }
       
      }
    }
  };
return (
    <>
      <div className="main__header">
        <div className="main__header-circle"></div>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search"
          placeholder="Search a word..."
          onChange={handleSearch}
        />
      </div>
      <div>{searchResult.pol}</div>
      <div>{searchResult.eng}</div>
      <div>{searchResult.ger}</div>
      <div>{searchResult.ned}</div>
      <div>{searchResult.spa}</div>
      <div>{searchResult.fra}</div>
      <div>{searchResult.ita}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

What's the problem? For example if I write "one" in searcher I want to show every words with "one" but in console.log is working good because it showing all possible words but in setSearchResult is saving only the last one. I was trying to do this by useEffect but also not working. How can I fix that, to save the same results to serachResult like in console.log ?
(in 'datas' are all words)

Answer (score 1):

The issue of the **searchResult** getting overwritten every time there is a new input from user is due to these 2 reasons:

1. **searchResult** variable is declared as an object, instead of as an array
2. The function to update **searchResult** is updating the old value (overwriting) instead of concatenating new data to the existing value.

**The issue can be resolved by making these 2 changes to the above code:**

**1. Declare the variable as an array.**

```
const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([])
```

**2. Concatenate new data to old value.**

```
const handleSearch = (e) => {
    const found = e.target.value
    if (found !== "") {
        for (let i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
            if (datas[i].pol.includes(found)) {
                setSearchResult([
                    ...searchResult, 
                    {pol: datas[i].pol, eng: datas[i].eng}
                ])
            }
        }
     }
//  ...
}
```

**More information:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZ5wKYbOM_I

https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-add-to-an-array-in-react-state-3d08ddb2e1dc

Comment: Isn't it better if the state update is done outside the loop instead of doing it inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Because setSearchResult is an object, you cant store same key multiple times, it will just overrride the value of given key, you need to change searchResult to be initialized as an array.

```
} else {
      const filteredData = datas.map(data => (
          data.pol.includes(finded) ||
          data.eng.includes(finded) ||
          data.ger.includes(finded) ||
          data.ned.includes(finded) ||
          data.spa.includes(finded) ||
          data.fra.includes(finded) ||
          data.ita.includes(finded)
        )}

          console.log(filteredData);

           setSearchResult(filteredData);

          console.log("searchResult", searchResult);
        }
       
      }
    }
```